# Crawl whole site except links under specific path

Tags: scrapy

I've got a scrappy spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spidermaster"
    allowed_domains = ["www.test.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.test.com/"]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()),
                  follow=True),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item'),
    ]
    def parse_item(self,response):
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
```

What im trying is to crawl the whole webpage except what is under an specific path.

For example, i want to crawl all the test web site except www.test.com/too_much_links.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give some examples of what you have tried, or if there is something that you are misunderstanding in the process of making the spider do what you want, elaborate on where you think the source of the misunderstanding lies.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it in this way:

```
ignore = ['too_much_links', 'many_links']

rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=ignore), follow=True),
         Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=ignore), callback='parse_item'),
]
```